# What is the Python way to walk a directory tree?

Tags: python, directory-walk

I feel that assigning files, and folders and doing the += [item] part is a bit hackish. Any suggestions? I'm using Python 3.2

```
from os import *
from os.path import *

def dir_contents(path):
    contents = listdir(path)
    files = []
    folders = []
    for i, item in enumerate(contents):
        if isfile(contents[i]):
            files += [item]
        elif isdir(contents[i]):
            folders += [item]
    return files, folders
```

Comment: Avoid `from x import *`. *That's* one piece of advice for Pythonic style.

Comment: This way of adding items to a list is hackish too. Add a single item with `files.append(item)` or multiple items with `files.extend([item1, item2, ...])`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75861500/6395822

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Take a look at the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/os.html#os.walk) function which returns the path along with the directories and files it contains. That should considerably shorten your solution.

Comment: Wow that's perfect, cant believe i missed it. Thanks you.

Comment: but `os.walk` isn't limited to one directory level like the OP's code is.

Answer (score 53):

`os.walk` and `os.scandir` are great options, however, I've been using *pathlib* more and more, and with pathlib you can use the `.glob()` or `.rglob()` (recursive glob) methods:

```
root_directory = Path(".")
for path_object in root_directory.rglob('*'):
    if path_object.is_file():
        print(f"hi, I'm a file: {path_object}")
    elif path_object.is_dir():
        print(f"hi, I'm a dir: {path_object}")
```

Comment: However, os.walk separates the files and the dirs for you already.  Also, just remembered: with os.walk, if I set topdown True (default), I can manipulate the subdirs list, and, for example, skip whole subtrees.  See the note about ** in large trees in the docs.

I wish os.walk could return Path objects.  (Stupid 5 minute edit limit)

Comment: You can replace `glob('**/*')` with `rglob('*')` which looks nicer.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone looking for a solution using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (`python >= 3.4`)

```
from pathlib import Path

def walk(path): 
    for p in Path(path).iterdir(): 
        if p.is_dir(): 
            yield from walk(p)
            continue
        yield p.resolve()

# recursively traverse all files from current directory
for p in walk(Path('.')): 
    print(p)

# the function returns a generator so if you need a list you need to build one
all_files = list(walk(Path('.')))
```

However, as mentioned above, this does not preserve the top-down ordering given by `os.walk`

Comment: I don't think I'd ever seen that `yield from` syntax before, or at least I'd forgotten about it. Thanks for illustrating it here! Relevant docs for posterity: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380

Comment: Note that the way this code is implemented means that only files will be listed, not directories.

Comment: I don't think the `continue` statement is needed; I get an identical result without it.

Comment: If you exclude the `continue` statement then it will also yield the directories. Otherwise you only get files. So it depends on what you want

Answer (score 9):

Since `Python >= 3.4` the exists the generator method `Path.rglob`.
So, to process all paths under `some/starting/path` just do something such as

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('some/starting/path') 
for subpath in path.rglob('*'):
    # do something with subpath
```

To get all subpaths in a list do `list(path.rglob('*'))`.
To get just the files with `sql` extension, do  `list(path.rglob('*.sql'))`.

Comment: I'll be using this everywhere from now on.  Pity the Python devs didn't default the first argument to '*' then it could be even shorter :)  Also with an empty string passed to rglob you seem to get the directories only if that's what you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to recursively iterate through all the files, including all files in the subfolders, I believe this is the best way.

```
import os

def get_files(input):
    for fd, subfds, fns in os.walk(input):
       for fn in fns:
            yield os.path.join(fd, fn)

## now this will print all full paths

for fn in get_files(fd):
    print(fn)
```

Comment: I really like this approach because it separates the file system iteration code from the code to process each file!  However, the "yield from" line needs to be omitted — `os.walk` already walks into subdirectories, so if you do it too, you see subdirectory files 2^n times.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution how to walk a directory tree using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for directory in Path('.').glob('**'):
    for item in directory.iterdir():
        print(item)
```

The pattern [`**`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) matches current directory and all subdirectories, recursively, and the method [`iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) then iterates over each directory's contents. Useful when you need more control when traversing the directory tree.

Answer (score 3):

```
def dir_contents(path):
    files,folders = [],[]
    for p in listdir(path):
        if isfile(p): files.append(p)
        else: folders.append(p)
    return files, folders
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed using

```
items += [item]
```

is bad for many reasons...

1. The `append` method has been made **exactly** for that (appending one element to the end of a list)
2. You are creating a temporary list of one element just to throw it away. While raw speed should not your first concern when using Python (otherwise you're using the wrong language) still wasting speed for no reason doesn't seem the right thing.
3. You are using a little asymmetry of the Python language... for list objects writing `a += b` is not the same as writing `a = a + b` because the former modifies the object in place, while the second instead allocates a new list and this can have a different semantic if the object `a` is also reachable using other ways. In your specific code this doesn't seem the case but it could become a problem later when someone else (or yourself in a few years, that is the same) will have to modify the code. Python even has a method `extend` with a less subtle syntax that is specifically made to handle the case in which you want to modify in place a list object by adding at the end the elements of another list.

Also as other have noted seems that your code is trying to do what `os.walk` already does...

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.4 there is new module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). So to get all dirs and files one can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

dirs = [str(item) for item in Path(path).iterdir() if item.is_dir()]
files = [str(item) for item in Path(path).iterdir() if item.is_file()]
```

Comment: iterdir() does not walk a tree recursively.

Comment: But... pathlib does support recursive globbing.

Comment: The method `iterdir()` [does not guarantee](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) the `os.walk()` [top-down ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). I would be extremely reticent to attempt to reimplement that tried-and-tested method. (**NOTE:** Some methods, like `os.rmdir()` can only delete an empty directory, so order can be very important.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the built-in os.walk and os.path.walk, I use something derived from this piece of code I found suggested elsewhere which I had originally linked to but have replaced with inlined source:

```
import os
import stat

class DirectoryStatWalker:
    # a forward iterator that traverses a directory tree, and
    # returns the filename and additional file information

    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.stack = [directory]
        self.files = []
        self.index = 0

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        while 1:
            try:
                file = self.files[self.index]
                self.index = self.index + 1
            except IndexError:
                # pop next directory from stack
                self.directory = self.stack.pop()
                self.files = os.listdir(self.directory)
                self.index = 0
            else:
                # got a filename
                fullname = os.path.join(self.directory, file)
                st = os.stat(fullname)
                mode = st[stat.ST_MODE]
                if stat.S_ISDIR(mode) and not stat.S_ISLNK(mode):
                    self.stack.append(fullname)
                return fullname, st

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file, st in DirectoryStatWalker("/usr/include"):
        print file, st[stat.ST_SIZE]
```

It walks the directories recursively and is quite efficient and easy to read.

Comment: +1 @mikebabcock thanks - this works for me out-of-the-box in Python 2.x (even though the OP is using 3.x) I needed a 2.x solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that project is no longer available, 404. Could someone repaste it here?

Comment: I haven't checked if its identical yet, but cf http://pymoex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/os_path/directoryStatWalker.py @LarsH

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that uses `os.scandir` and returns a tree structure. Using `os.scandir` will return `os.DirEntry` objects, which hold information about the path objects in memory, allowing querying of the information about the items without filesystem calls.

```
import os

def treedir(path):
    files = []
    folders = {}
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_file():
            files.append(entry)
        elif entry.is_dir():
            folders[entry.name] = treedir(entry)
    result = {}
    if files:
        result['files'] = files
    if folders:
        result['folders'] = folders
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`append`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method.

Comment: +1: this is also far better than `list += [item]`. The *batteries are inccluded* and familiarity with the core language features stops you from reinventing the battery: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included

Answer (score 0):

While googling for the same info, I found this question.

I am posting here the smallest, clearest code which I found at http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/ (rather than just posting the URL, in case of link rot).

The page has some useful info and also points to a few other relevant pages.

```
# Import the os module, for the os.walk function
import os

# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this extensively yet, but I believe
 this will expand the `os.walk` generator, join dirnames to all the file paths, and flatten the resulting list; To give a straight up list of concrete files in your search path.

```
import itertools
import os

def find(input_path):
    return itertools.chain(
        *list(
            list(os.path.join(dirname, fname) for fname in files)
            for dirname, _, files in os.walk(input_path)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pathlib
import time

def prune_empty_dirs(path: pathlib.Path):
    for current_path in list(path.rglob("*"))[::-1]:
        if current_path.is_dir() and not any(current_path.iterdir()):
            current_path.rmdir()
            while current_path.exists():
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I like the structure of the result of `os.walk()` but prefer `pathlib` overall. My lazy solution therefore is simply creating a `Path` from each item returned by `os.walk()`.

```py
import os
import pathlib


def walk(path='bin'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        root = pathlib.Path(root)
        dirs = [root / d for d in dirs]
        files = [root / f for f in files]
        yield root, dirs, files
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste code for those who want to deep walk all nested sub directories:

- using python's `recursion call` with `os.listdir()`:

```py
import os

count = 0
def deep_walk(mypath):
    global count
    for file in os.listdir(mypath):
        file_path = os.path.join(mypath, file)
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            deep_walk(file_path)
        else:
            count += 1
            print(file_path)

mypath="/tmp"
deep_walk(mypath)
print(f"Total file count: {count}")
```

- using python's standard library `os.walk()`:

```py
import os

def walk_dir(mypath):
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            count += 1
            print(file_path)
    print(f"Total file count: {count}")

mypath = "/tmp"
walk_dir(mypath)
```

The difference is that with `os.walk()` you won't need to walk every directories of each sub directories mannually, the library will do it for you, no matter how many nested directories you have.