# Recursively iterate through all subdirectories using pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

How can I use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to recursively iterate over all subdirectories of a given directory?

```
p = Path('docs')
for child in p.iterdir():
    # do things with child
```

only seems to iterate over the immediate children of a given directory.

I know this is possible with `os.walk()` or `glob`, but I want to use pathlib because I like working with the path objects.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method of a `Path` object:

```
p = Path('docs')
for i in p.glob('**/*'):
     print(i.name)
```

Comment: There's also a `rglob` method, which adds `**/` before the pattern, so you can do `p.rglob('*')` instead.

Comment: Yes as per @pylang's answer below. Thought it would be rude to update mine as he's had good success so far.

Comment: You have upstanding character @JacquesGaudin. Cheers.

Answer (score 271):

Use [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) (substitutes the leading `**` in `Path().glob("**/*")`):

```
path = Path("docs")
for p in path.rglob("*"):
    print(p.name)
```

Comment: This is nice, you can also add the file extension e.g. ```for p in path.rglob("*.pdf"):```

Answer (score 19):

To find just folders the right glob string is:

```
'**/'
```

So to find all the paths for all the folders in your path do this:

```
p = Path('docs')
for child in p.glob('**/'):
    print(child)
```

If you just want the folder names without the paths then print the name of the folder like so:

```
p = Path('docs')
for child in p.glob('**/'):
    print(child.name)
```

Comment: To find just folders using `rglob`: `p.rglob("./")`

Answer (score 13):

As of Python 3.12 use `pathlib.Path.walk()`

```
import pathlib    
path = pathlib.Path(r"E:\folder")
for root, dirs, files in path.walk():
    print("Root: ")
    print(root)
    print("Dirs: ")
    print(dirs)
    print("Files: ")
    print(files)
    print("")
```

Answer (score 10):

`pathlib` has `glob` method where we can provide pattern as an argument.

For example : `Path('abc').glob('**/*.txt')` - It will look for current folder `abc` and all other subdirectories recursively to locate all `txt` files.

Answer (score 10):

Use list comprehensions:

```
(1) [f.name for f in p.glob("**/*")]  # or
(2) [f.name for f in p.rglob("*")]
```

You can add `if f.is_file()` or `if f.is_dir()` to (1) or (2) if you want to target files only or directories only, respectively. Or replace `"*"` with some pattern like `"*.txt"` if you want to target `.txt` files only.

See this quick [guide](https://medium.com/swlh/five-most-useful-pathlib-operations-77f9c96790b3?source=friends_link&sk=1af6c42532eff5cbe149f19f49f1450d).

Comment: What is the point in using list comprehension? How does that complement the existing answers?

Comment: I was looking at the other answers that were printing the results, so I was offering it as an alternative. But you're right, the original post doesn't make it explicit it's needed.

Comment: We might as well add generator expressions as well.