# Given a directory with sub directories, how can I find a file's path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, io, path

Let's assume that I have the following nested directories structure:

```
my_dir
|---- dir_1
|---- dir_2
|---- dir_3
      |---- dir_4
            |---- dir_5
                  |---- dir_6
                        |---- my_file.txt
```

How can I look if `my_file.txt` exists in any of the sub-directories of `dir_3`  (e.g. `dir_4`, `dir_5`, `dir_6`), and if exists how can I get its path? At the moment I tried with:

```
def file(name, path):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(abspath(path)):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(r, n)
    else:
         return 'file not found'
```

However, the above function is odd. How can I do the same with Pathlib?

Comment: Since you're using Python 3, you should take a look at the `pathlib` module.

Comment: could you put a solution using pathlib?

Comment: I edited the quesiton

Comment: You should spend a little time learning about pathlib. You can probably use `pathlib.glob` to do what you want. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50714469/4014959

Answer (score 1):

delete your 'else' branch, so that you can continue walking the dir tree.
then after the for loop, you can return 'file not found'.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linux shell command

```
import os
cmd = 'find my_dir -name myfile.txt'
os.system(cmd)
```

This will search for myfile.txt in my_dir directory

or using subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["find","my_dir","-name","myfile.txt"])
```