# How do I recursively iterate over just the files in a directory using pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a directory, and I want to get all the *files* (no directories) inside it, and all the files inside of any of its subdirectories and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) or [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to [recursively iterate over both files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714469/recursively-iterate-through-all-subdirectories-using-pathlib) and then skip anything that doesn't return `True` for [`Path.is_file()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file)

```
from pathlib import Path

def iter_files(path):
    for file_or_directory in path.rglob("*"):
        if file_or_directory.is_file():
            yield file_or_directory
```

Then you can use that generator like this

```
my_path = Path("/some/path/here")

for my_file in iter_files(my_path):
    do_whatever(my_file)
```

You can use the same principle in a list comprehension

```
files = [path for path in my_path.rglob("*") if path.is_file()]
```