# Get files from specific folders in python

Tags: python, file, listdir

I have the following directory structure with the following files:

```
Folder_One
├─file1.txt
├─file1.doc
└─file2.txt
Folder_Two
├─file2.txt
├─file2.doc
└─file3.txt
```

I would like to get only the .txt files from each folder listed. Example:

```
Folder_One-> file1.txt and file2.txt
Folder_Two-> file2.txt and file3.txt
```

**Note:** This entire directory is inside a folder called dataset. My code looks like this, but I believe something is missing. Can someone help me.

```
path_dataset = "./dataset/"
filedataset = os.listdir(path_dataset)
    
    for i in filedataset:
        pasta = ''
        pasta = pasta.join(i) 
        for file in glob.glob(path_dataset+"*.txt"):
            print(file)
```

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/50714469/4531270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` module to check that filename ends with `.txt`.

```
import re
import os
path_dataset = "./dataset/"
l = os.listdir(path_dataset)

for e in l:
   if os.path.isdir("./dataset/" + e):
      ll = os.listdir(path_dataset + e)
      for file in ll:
          if re.match(r".*\.txt$", file):
              print(e + '->' + file)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path('dataset').rglob('*.txt'):
    print(path.name)
```

Using `glob`

```
import glob
for x in glob.glob('dataset/**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

One may use an additional option to check and find all files by using the `os` module (this is of advantage if you already use this module):

```
import os
#get current directory, you may also provide an absolute path
path=os.getcwd() 
#walk recursivly through all folders and gather information
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    #check if file is of correct type 
    check=[f for f in files if f.find(".txt")!=-1]
    if check!=[]:print(root,check)
```