# Can Pathlib iterdir be used to recursively iterate through a directory structure like os.walk?

Tags: python-3.x

I know that *glob* exists for this purpose and one can also use *os.walk* to get a list of all subdirectories and files inside a folder and use this to create a tree of **all** files and folders that exist inside a root directory. However, can one also use the Pathlib iterdir function to recursively iterate through all subdirectories inside a folder and store the paths to all files and the filenames like we can do so easily with os.walk?

I am asking this question since as per my knowledge, the Pathlib actually presents better way to do things already done by os and os.path.

Comment: Please let me know if an answer already exists to this question.

Comment: Why can't you use `Path.glob` (**not** the glob module)? ie. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714469/recursively-iterate-through-all-subdirectories-using-pathlib

Comment: I want to literally iterate through the root directory, comparing the folder name and filename with regular expressions and if they match, add the resulting file and full path into a list or dictionary.

Comment: Path.glob or just glob, what is the difference?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75861500/6395822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is strings, or if you need to prune directories or control the order of traversal, then `os.walk` is the correct tool. For other tasks when you need `Path` objects then `pathlib` might be better.

For most use cases, at least those provided by `os.path` then `pathlib` can be simpler and more elegant. But, `pathlib` is not a better replacement for all related functionality in `os`. `os.walk` is a clear example of a use case that `pathlib` does not support as well.

**Update December 2023:**

As of Python 3.12, `pathlib.Path` objects now have a `.walk()` method, which provides functionality equivalent to `os.walk()`.

Comment: yes, I use the .walk method. Just love it.