# using pathlib to copy files from subdirectories to other subdirectories based on file.name

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, pathlib, copying

Directory 1 contains subfolders of student info, each subfolder is named with the following convention

```
LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME (STUDENTNUMBER)
```

Directory 2 has 6 subfolders that contain `.xlsx` student grade sheets in them, each of these excel files is named with the following convention

```
LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME (STUDENTNUMBER) marking sheet.xlsx
```

I'd like to use pathlib to take the names of the subfolders in directory 1 and find the matching grading sheet in the subfolders in directory 2.

For example:

```
import pathlib as pl

dir1 = pl.WindowsPath(r'C:\Users\username\directory_1')
dir2 = pl.WindowsPath(r'C:\Users\username\directory_2')

for (subfolder, file) in zip(dir1.iterdir(), dir2.rglob("*.xlsx")):
    if str.lower(subfolder.name) is in str.lower(file.name): #I run up against a wall here
        copy file into subfolder
        print(f'{file.name} copied to {subfolder.name}')
```

Apologies if this question is unclear but any assistance would be appreciated. I have also tried to impliment ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714469/recursively-iterate-through-all-subdirectories-using-pathlib)  but I'm not skilled enough with python to modify it for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but I think what you want to be doing is creating the potential file name from the subfolders in directory 1, using that to search in directory 2 and then moving files that you find.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy

dir1 = Path("C:\Users\username\directory_1")
dir2 = Path("C:\Users\username\directory_2")

for folder in dir1.iterdir():
    # We're only interested in folders
    if not folder.is_dir():
        continue

    target_file = f"{folder.name} marking sheet.xlsx"
    for file in dir2.rglob(target_file):
        # copy(file, dest)
```

I'm not sure about where you want the files to be copied to, but you can set the `dest` variable for each subfolder of `dir1` or result of the `rglob`. Another thing to note, you may find multiple files with the target name in different directories so I would caution against copying them all to the same place!

Comment: Thank you very much, I see what you're doing here. ```dest``` is the folder in dir1. So I want to take the folder name in dir1 and use that to find a .xlsx file in dir2 and copy that file into the subfolder in dir1 that shares the name. I can play around with what you've written and post back. Thanks a million for your time @Alex

Comment: Ah, yes, that's certainly do-able. If you want I can expand my answer with what I would do, but I don't want to stop you finding the answer yourself! Sometimes all it takes is pointing in the right direction

Comment: I'm on another task for a couple of hours but I'll post my version of this in a few hours, thanks again for the help.