# Merge all .xlsx of same name in all subdirectory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How can I merge all the xlsx with a specific name in a given folder and subfolder. I mean it want it to recurse and find all the .xlsx with the same name

Comment: It's impossible for 2 files to have the same name in the same folder

Comment: @mousetail I meant to same in the sub-folders

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714469/recursively-iterate-through-all-subdirectories-using-pathlib) about recursively iteration

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Perhaps give a example of what you have and what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure used

[image]

**Check this out and check whether it works you!**

```
import glob
from pprint import pprint

your_folder_path = os.path.relpath(os.getcwd())

def list_all_xlsx(path):
    return [files for files in os.listdir(path) if files[-4:]=="xlsx"]

filemap = {}
all_files = []

for path in glob.glob(f'{your_folder_path}') + glob.glob(f'{your_folder_path}/*/**/', recursive=True):
    filemap[path] = list_all_xlsx(path)
    all_files.extend(filemap[path])
unique_files = set(all_files)

print(unique_files)  #prints all the files found in that folder and its subfolders
print(filemap)    #dictionary holding files found in that folder and its subfolders

final_dict = {each:[] for each in unique_files}

for key, value in filemap.items():
    for each in unique_files:
        if each in value:
            final_dict[each].append(key)

for k,v in final_dict.items():
    if(len(v) > 1):   # condition to check a file found in multiple folders
        print("file", k, "found in these directories", v)
```

My output:
[image]