# Pathlib alternative for os.walk(dir_name)

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

Original code :

```
for dir_name, dir_path, file_name in os.walk(dir):
    doSomething()
```

What can we use from pathlib module instead of os.walk().

Thankss....

Comment: Why is this down-voted? Just running into this because manipulating Path is much easier and to parse each path string into a Path instance appears to be quite wasteful with CPU-resources.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75861500/6395822

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively iterate through all subdirectories using pathlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714469/recursively-iterate-through-all-subdirectories-using-pathlib)

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.12 adds `pathlib.Path.walk()`.
https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.walk

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is : nothing. The pathlib module does not implement such a function.

However, implementing one yourself is fairly trivial :

```py
def my_walk(mydir: pathlib.Path):
    '''like os.walk, but using pathlib.Path, and with fewer options'''
    subdirs = list(d for d in mydir.iterdir() if d.is_dir())
    files = list(f for f in mydir.iterdir() if f.is_file())
    yield mydir, subdirs, files
    for s in subdirs:
        yield from my_walk(s)

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk('.'):
    print(dir_path, dir_names, file_names)

for dir_path, subdir_paths, file_paths in my_walk(pathlib.Path('.')):
    print(dir_path, subdir_paths, file_paths)
```

That being said, I'm not sure why it would not be simpler to `import os` and then `os.walk`.