# repeat exact same code on different directories with `try` `except` in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a python script that parses information from different files into pandas dataframes. At first, I am aiming at a certain directory, then I am calling the commands to parse the information from multiple files. If, however, that directory does not exist, I should execute the exact same code, though in another directory. To illustrate, it should be something like:

```
import os
try:
    cwd = "/path/do/dir"
    os.chdir(cwd)
    #do a code block here

except FileNotFoundError: # i.e. in case /path/to/dir does not exist
    cwd = /path/to/anotherDir
    os.chdir(cwd)
    # do the same code block
```

What I am doing currently is to repeat the same code block in the `try` and in the `except` chunks, though I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it, like assigning the whole code block to a variable or a function, then calling this variable/ function in the `except chunk`.

Comment: How about looping through with `for file in files:` and put a `try` and `except` inside the loop?

Comment: What is it actually you are trying to achieve? This looking you are recursively trying to walk a directory tree; use `os.walk` for that instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639394/what-is-the-python-way-to-walk-a-directory-tree

Also, you should always try to keep the scope of your try / except blocks as minimal as possible: otherwise, an error in the except clause will still be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over a list of paths, and try your code block for every file.
You can even add a `break` at the end of your `try` block if you want to stop iterating as soon as you found a path that worked.

```
paths = ['path/to/dir', 'path/to/other/dir']

for cwd in paths:
    try:
        os.chdir(cwd)

        # code that may fail here

        break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # This will NOT cause the code to fail; it's the same as `pass` but
        # more informative
        print("File not found:", cwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to simply check if the directory/file exists?

```
import os
if os.path.isdir('some/path') and os.path.isfile('some/path/file.txt'):
    os.chdir('some/path')
else:
    os.chdir('other/path')

#code block here
```

Of course, this assumes that nothing else can go wrong in the '#code block'.