# How to make the recursion work to show all the directories and their subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I want to print all the directories and their subdirectories and so on. I used recursion for that. But it is giving me the following error?

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    filesystem("/home/runner/TestP1")
  File "main.py", line 17, in filesystem
    filesystem(dirs)
  File "main.py", line 11, in filesystem
    dirfiles = os.listdir(dirname)
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not list
```

**Code**

```
import os

def filesystem(dirname):
    dirfiles = os.listdir(dirname)
    fullpaths = map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirname, name), dirfiles)
    dirs = []

    for file in fullpaths:
        if os.path.isdir(file): dirs.append(file)
    filesystem(dirs)
    print(list(dirs))

filesystem("/home/runner/TestP1")
```

Comment: Have you considered using `os.walk()` / `os.fwalk()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `filesystem(dirs)` by:

```
for dirname in dirs:
    filesystem(dirs)
```

Also note that:

1. In 2021, you should be using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Especially `glob` is unbelievably useful.
2. In Linux, take care with symlinks / hardlinks, which might easily cause endless recursion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639394/what-is-the-python-way-to-walk-a-directory-tree